How to run/install KDE Discover Store on CachyOS?
I just installed CachyOS with the KDE Plasma Desktop Environment, and I can see in my taskbar that there is a Discover Store:

But when I click on it, then I get an error popup:

No matter how I try to run it, it doesn't run.
Did it maybe not install correctly with my CachyOS installation? What would cause this?
I even reinstalled CachyOS completely three times from start and every time the Discover Store doesn't work.

After a long time of struggling, I managed to figure out that I can install it with the following way:

Open Konsole App (Ctrl+Alt+T)
Run sudo pacman -Sy
Run sudo pacman -S discover flatpack

And now the Discover Store works.
